# Why aren't CC numbers asterik'ed out?

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.3, credit-card

Perhaps I've never noticed this or is it just my system? What's an easy way to apply the asterisks?

[image]

Comment: dont understand completely can you please explain your Q

Comment: Do you see the CC numbers in the input above in my image. 411111111111111...... Shouldn't they be **************** so you can't see them. @AsadUllah

Comment: at checkout i dont think so

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to do it with JavaScript with a delay. So user can see what they type. An example here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/mask-password-asterisk-passwordify/